# Creating a full width slider with custom icons as pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css, pagination, slider

I am attempting to create a full width JQuery slider with custom icons as the pagination. The image will slide vertically when each icon is clicked and the icon will remain highlighted with that sections title replacing the icon (active link). What would be the best way to go about doing this? I have not written any code yet so please dont ask me to post any. If someone could be so kind as to guide me through maybe the first slide, Ill most likely be able to achieve the rest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iOSSlider](https://iosscripts.com/iosslider/) is pretty good, and well worth the $15 license fee. You should be able to achieve custom icons regardless of which plugin you use -  just CSS selectors to set the background image for each element by index.